# Any suggestions about how to achieve such formatting in Latex?

Tags: graphics, sectioning, formatting, pdftex, color

I am in the mid of a project, where I am required to design a document which has similar formatting to the one attached in images. I have good idea about laying out text in two column format, changing the colour of text rendered, modifying the size of the text.

But I had some doubts regarding the document design in latex in which I need some help which are:

1. How can I design the border formatting as in the images?
2. How to design the headings as in the document, like having some graphics in background and text in foreground?
3. How can easily manage the formatting style like the text in coloured boxes in some places.

Any other help if somebody has any idea about some package which can easily allow me to achieve such formatting in my documents will be great.
[image: Formatting Style 1]
[image]

Comment: Don´t use LaTeX for that.

Comment: @Johannes_B I am looking to design documents with random content (random images and text) with similar formatting, and generating a latex script which can generate random documents will be simple, only if I have idea about how to get similar formatting. Can you suggest any other solutions to this?

Comment: Questions asking us to **how do I draw this in LaTeX** are not really on-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I don't think LaTeX is the best choice for your task. Unfortunately, i don't have a better alternative.

Comment: @Johannes_B I agree with you completely. I'll have to do this using latex only, but couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: @JVJ Maybe you could break down the question into smaller bits? For example "How to draw this boarder with page number". In it's current state answering this question would require a lot of work.

Comment: Also have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends There might not be the exact same design, but it shows some heavily customised documents where you can get some techniques from.

Comment: I'll work on your suggestions @samcarter. Nice idea, to decompose rendering of style-items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it is probably possible, LaTeX is not a tool for doing designs of this nature. The work of making the code would be extremely large, and you'd probably end up spending way too much time making this.

You should use some other software like Adobe InDesign or Scribus.

The reason is just that LaTeX is not made for this kind of formatting, but for *text processing* (and some other posters and the like). It's hard to define a hard difference where it becomes difficult, but when you want to experiment a lot with element positions, getting small images connected with other elements in specific positions, that's when it gets hard.